# extracting (international) phone numbers from text

Tags: php, regex, information-extraction

I am looking for a way of extracting international phone numbers from text.

In other words, inputting the text below:

"this test +44 (0) 7961617600 Reconfirmation Notes Transfer to London train station (Mon, Apr 25) Pax : 45 + 1 BM Coaches Confirm +32 (020) 9948 7711 - Gaynor Reconfirmation is required by Apr 23. \n\nConfirmed with on at Day 4 : Monday, April 25, 2011 (Sun, Apr 24)"

would output: 
+44 (0) 7961617600
+32 (020) 9948 7711

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are using, but you might be able to just grep all the numbers from textfiles in a directory.

If the + will always be there it can be an anchor.  In vim something like this could get the numbers in a folder, but it is loose

```
:lvim /+\d\{1}\([0-9 ()]\{9,}\)\d\{1}/gj *.txt
```

if you're sure there will be a (123) piece this could tighten it up

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
I'm using PHP. How might I use your regex in this script?